# Sending Session Data in Email

Tags: php, forms, email, session, session-variables

I have a multi page form that i am storing the data in a session. I've used some examples here to get this to work. I am now really stuck.

```
//let's start the session
session_start();

//now, let's register our session variables
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
$_SESSION['all_quote_details'][$k]=$v;
}
print_r($_SESSION);
```

The values are printing to screen

I am trying to send in an email. I have tried many different ways and cannot get it to work. I have the following which is only coded for the the first two inputs for testing

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION['all_quote_details'] as $result){ 
$result .="Name: ".$result['Name'].", Email: ".$result['Email']."\n"; 
}


$to      = 'dan@dentalseoltd.co.uk';
$subject = 'TESTING ';
$message = "<td>Please See Quote   $value;</td>";


mail($to, $subject, $message,$body, $headers); 

?>
```

Previous trials to get this to work would either send me a blank email or just simply 
`Array`.

This time I am getting

> ```
> '<td>Please See Quote Name: , Email:
> Name: , Email:
> Name: , Email:
> Name: , Email:
> Name: , Email:
> Name: , Email:
> Name: b, Email: b
> Name: 3, Email: 3
> Name: 3, Email: 3
> Name: D, Email: D
> Name: , Email:
> Name: 1, Email: 1
> Name: c, Email: c
> Name: f, Email: f
> Name: h, Email: h
> Name: 2, Email: 2
> Name: 4, Email: 4
> Name: n, Email: n
> Name: b, Email: b
> Name: l, Email: l
> Name: n, Email: n
> Name: n, Email: n
> Name: , Email:
> ;</td> '
> ```

Comment: Turn on error reporting and see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: Is your every post variable itself an array? `$v['Name'] and $v['Email']`

Comment: no its just the above session code on the form. then the second code is the post.php code which is on the form action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between your two examples.

In the first case you are handling the session value as dictionary and in the second as an array of dictionaries.

What gives you?

```
foreach ($_SESSION['all_quote_details'] as $k => $v){ 
    $result .="Name: ". $k.", Email: ".$v."\n"; 
}
```

Comment: I changed your code to the following in my email post.php '<?php
session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION['all_quote_details'] as $k => $v){ 
    $result .="". $k.",  ".$v."\n"; 
}

$to      = 'dan@dentalseoltd.co.uk';
$subject = 'TESTING ';
$message = "<td>Please See Quote   $result;</td>";


    mail($to, $subject, $message,$body, $headers); 


?>' It worked :) i have been trying for days to get this to work. I cant thankyou enough! I really appeciate you taking the time to answer and create that code for me

Comment: Hi, okay so i have broken it :) when i remove the print_r($_SESSION); it just sends a blank email but with this on it displays the data on the screen to the user? Do you know a way around this?

Comment: Can you send me the relevant part of your script?